# Using pandas over csv library for manipulating CSV files in Python3

Tags: python, csv

Forgive me if my questions is too general, or if its been asked before. I've been tasked to manipulate (e.g. copy and paste several range of entries, perform calculations on them, and then save them all to a new csv file) several large datasets in Python3.

What are the pros/cons of using the aforementioned libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used CSV library, but many people are enjoying the benefits of Pandas.  Pandas provides a lot of the tools you'll need, based off Numpy.  You can easily then use more advance libraries for all sorts of analysis (sklearn for machine learning, nltk for nlp, etc.).

For your purposes, you'll find it easy to manage different cdv's, merge, concatenate, do whatever you want really.

Heres a link to a quick start guide.  Lots of other resources out there as well.

getting started with pandas python
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Hope that helps a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to use as much as possible the work that other people have already been doing for you (such as programming the pandas library). This saves you a lot of time. Pandas has a lot to offer when you want to process such files so this seems to me to be the the best way to deal with such files. Since the question is very general, I can also only give a general answer... When you use pandas, you will however need to read more in the documentation. But I would not say that this is a downside.